# How to update listview automatically after adding a new item into DB

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm using C# WPF MVVM. So in XAML there is a listview, which is binded to an object, used to show different information from sql database depending on tab.

For example. I have two forms: one is that shows information and another that is used to input information. How can I automatically update the listview in one form, after new information was entered in another form? Because now I have to switch tabs to get the listview updated.

Comment: by listening to events? with this vague question (no code) you wont find much of help here.

Comment: I guess by listeting events...

Answer (score 1):

binding direction for this element should be exposed to  **TwoWay**    (Mode=TwoWay)

like this:

> x:Name="list"
>               ItemsSource="{Binding .......  , Path=........., Mode=TwoWay}}" ......

Apart from the default binding, which is one way, you can also configure binding to be two way, one way to source, and so forth.  This is done by specifying the Mode property.

**OneWay**: Causes changes to the source property to automatically update the target property but the source does not get changed 
**TwoWay**: Changes in the source or target automatically cause updates to the other 
**OneWayToSource**: Causes changes to the target property to automatically update the source property but the target does not get changed 
**OneTime**: Causes only the first time change to the source property to automatically update the target property but the source does not get changed and subsequent changes do not affect the target property

you can look this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: To my mind the problem is that I should update binded to listview object somehow.

Comment: look same examples, they will help you   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part-1

Comment: I have Listview binded to an Object, which contains all information. Object gets information from SQL database using NHibernate. But it doesn't get updated after new information was added to the database. So binding won't help me. To my mind...

Answer (score 1):

After you enter new information into a form, try to invoke your own method, which will update your information into a list view. 
So you can use some event eg. `DataContentChanged` or your update method can be called when u click the button which adds new data into your form.
Example of refresh method should look like this:

```
public void lbRefresh()        
{
    //create itemsList for listbox
    ArrayList itemsList = new ArrayList();
    //count how many information you wana to add
    //here I count how many columns I have in dataGrid1
    int count = dataGrid1.Columns.Count;
    //for cycle to add my strings of columns headers into an itemsList
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        itemsList.Add(dataGrid1.Columns[i].Header.ToString());
    }
    //simply refresh my itemsList into my listBox1
    listBox1.ItemsSource = itemsList;
}
```

EDIT: To finish and solve your problem, try to use this snippet of code:

```
//some btn_Click Event in one window 
//(lets say, its your callback " to update" button in datagrid)
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //here you doing somethin
    //after your datagrid got updated, try to store the object, 
    //which u want to send into your eg. listbox

    data[0] = data; //my stored data in array

    //for better understanding, this method "Button_Click_1" is called from Window1.xaml.cs
    //and I want to pass information into my another window Graph1.xaml.cs

    //create "newWindow" object onto your another window and send "data" by constuctor
    var newWindow = new Graph1(data); //line *
    //you can call this if u want to show that window after changes applied
    newWindow.Show();
}
```

After that your Graph1.xaml.cs should look like this:

```
public partial class Graph1 : Window
{//this method takes over your data u sent by line * into previous method explained
    public Graph1(int[]data) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //now you can direcly use your "data" or can call another method and pass your data into it
        ownListBoxUpdateMethod(data);

    }
    private void ownListBoxUpdateMethod(int[] data)
    {
        //update your listbox here and its done ;-)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Actually it is the most suitable for me. The problem is that I don't have direct access to listview from programm code, because it's MVVM. So I have to update Object somehow. But I guess that I'm close to solve the problem.